# "The parameterized query expects the parameter , which was not supplied." But it is supplied

Tags: c#, parameterized-query

```
public void InsertBaselineDetailsToExistingBaseline(BaselineSummary summary)
{
    var sqlConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PdsLoadTesting"].ConnectionString;

    if (summary.BaselineId != null)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var baselineDetailCommand = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                baselineDetailCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.baselinedetail (BaselineDetailId, BaselineId, Endpoint, PostData, RequestMethod, ComparisonType, InactiveTest, RunOrder, ScenarioDescription, EndpointPattern) VALUES (@BaselineDetailId, @BaselineId, @Endpoint, @PostData, @RequestMethod, @ComparisonType, 0, @RunOrder, @ScenarioDescription, @EndpointPattern)";

                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@BaselineDetailId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@BaselineId", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier);
                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@Endpoint", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@PostData", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@RequestMethod", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@ComparisonType", SqlDbType.VarChar);
                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@RunOrder", SqlDbType.Int);
                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@ScenarioDescription", SqlDbType.Int);
                baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndpointPattern", SqlDbType.VarChar);

                foreach (var baselineDetail in summary.Details)
                {
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@BaselineDetailId"].Value = Guid.NewGuid();
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@BaselineId"].Value = summary.BaselineId;
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@Endpoint"].Value = baselineDetail.Endpoint;
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@PostData"].Value = string.IsNullOrEmpty(baselineDetail.PostData) ? (object)DBNull.Value : baselineDetail.PostData;
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@RequestMethod"].Value = baselineDetail.RequestMethod;
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@ComparisonType"].Value = baselineDetail.ComparisonType;
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@RunOrder"].Value = (object)baselineDetail.RunOrder ?? DBNull.Value;
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@ScenarioDescription"].Value = baselineDetail.ScenarioDescription;
                    baselineDetailCommand.Parameters["@EndpointPattern"].Value = baselineDetail.EndpointPattern;

                    baselineDetailCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the method above I get an error

> The parameterized query expects the parameter @PostData, which was not supplied.

The parameter is supplied and I am also checking for null and passing `DBNull.Value` if the parameter is indeed null. Null is valid value for `@PostData` in this situation.

Any suggestions as to why this method is still returning this error?

Comment: Without have your exact code I can only guess but say I have gotten this error.  Namely it means that what SQL is getting and not your code in ADO.NET is sending is not the same.  It usually comes from:  A. Your name is slightly different in one or the other.  or B. You are sending in a null when you have that parameter in SQL Server set as Not null and hence would want an empty string and not a DB Null value.  Just a thought, may be right may be wrong. If you are sure the names are right I would set a string to be something like "test".

Comment: Its possible you are never entering this loop: `foreach (var baselineDetail in summary.Details)` to set the parameter values and thus sql server is yelling at you.

Comment: What is `baselineDetail.PostData` & `summary.Details`? I think your `foreach` loop potentially skipped if `summary.Details` is empty. Why not trying assignment inside `foreach` loop such like `baselineDetailCommand.Parameters.Add("@Endpoint", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = baselineDetail.Endpoint;`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi - if the loop was skipped then the code would never call `ExecuteNonQuery` and so we'd never get the error in the first place.

Comment: @djangojazz - I know this response is several years after you answered it, but I wanted to thank you for a moment. I'm in VB.NET and received the say error, but it was because I was attempting to test a scalar command and I was passing in Nothing (aka null) as the value. Changing it to a bunk value worked.